# R - Leave one out aggregation on a grouping variable (NA exist)

Tags: sql, r

I want to compute new variables from the "Have" data set, in R, as follows:

RE:  the average of "R" values within a given "Cat" variable value excluding the specific observation (note:  missing data exists and I would like RE to be the group mean for RE when R is missing).

IE:  as with RE, the average of "I" responses within a given "Cat" variable value excluding the specific observation (same missing data technique).

An example data set and desired output is given below.

Have:

```
ID  CAT R   I   … (Additional variables I need to retain)
1   1   1   3   …
2   1   2   NA  …
3   1   1   1   …
4   2   NA  3   …
5   2   4   5   …
6   2   4   NA  …
```

The desired data set ("Want") should then be:

Want:

```
ID  CAT R   I   RE   IE     … (Additional variables retained)
1   1   1   3   1.5  1      …
2   1   2   NA  1    2      …
3   1   1   1   1.5  3      …
4   2   NA  3   ...  ...    …
5   2   4   5               …
6   2   4   NA              …
```

Notably, the following sql based solution produces the desired output in *SAS*, but I am unable to get it working in R (using the sqldf package).  One issue I'm aware of is that the missing function is SAS specific (not available in SQL universally). All said, this might provide a helpful starting point for a SQL solution using the sqldf package:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select *, 
  (sum(R)-coalesce(R, 0))/(count(R)-1+missing(R)) as RE,
  (sum(I)-coalesce(I, 0))/(count(I)-1+missing(I)) as IE
from have
group by CAT
order by ID, CAT;
quit;
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can apply a function to a subset of rows without affecting the other rows, sort of like 'windowing' in sql if you are familiar with the concept in that domain.

Create a function to carry out the desired calculation for one ID group. Group rows using `group_by()`, then pipe the result to `mutate()` and run the custom function. With grouped data it will only affect one group at a time and give the desired result.

```
library(dplyr)

# Data from example
have <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
"ID  CAT R   I   
1   1   1   3   
2   1   2   NA  
3   1   1   1   
4   2   NA  3   
5   2   4   5   
6   2   4   NA")

# Create a leave-one-out mean function -- for a single ID group

leave_one_out_mean <- function(x) {
    result <- c()

    for ( i in seq_along(x) ) {
        # note minus-i subsetting is used to subset one observation in each iteration
        # and the na.rm option to handle missing values
        result[i] <- mean(x[-i], na.rm = TRUE) 
    }

    return(result)
}

# Use group by but _do not_ pipe the result through summarize()

want <- have %>%
    group_by(CAT) %>%
    mutate(RE = leave_one_out_mean(R),
           IE = leave_one_out_mean(I))
```

Result

```
want

Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
Groups: CAT [2]

     ID   CAT     R     I    RE    IE
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     3   1.5     1
2     2     1     2    NA   1.0     2
3     3     1     1     1   1.5     3
4     4     2    NA     3   4.0     5
5     5     2     4     5   4.0     3
6     6     2     4    NA   4.0     4
```

The `for` loop could be replaced with an apply function, but I wrote it this way to highlight the logic rather than optimize execution.

Comment: Thanks, this works well.  Could you also demonstrate with the apply function for optimized execution?

Comment: What I had in mind was replacing the body of the function with `sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) mean(x[-i], na.rm = TRUE))` -- but I didn't confirm that it's actually faster

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution, without loop, inspired by your SQL code.

```
d <- read.table(text = 
'ID  CAT R   I 
1   1   1   3
2   1   2   NA
3   1   1   1
4   2   NA  3
5   2   4   5
6   2   4   NA', header = TRUE)

myfunc <- function(x) {
    tmp <- x ; tmp[is.na(tmp)] <- 0
    ((sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)-tmp)/(length(x[!is.na(x)])-1 + is.na(x)))
}
RE <- as.vector(t(aggregate(d["R"], d["CAT"], myfunc)$R))
IE <- as.vector(t(aggregate(d["I"], d["CAT"], myfunc)$I))

cbind(d, RE, IE)
```

Comment: Also a helpful solution, although I must have had something off on cbind, the datasets were not joined.